# Trying to fit iMac 27 Late 2013 memory into iMac 27 Late 2009

Tags: imac, memory

When shoving the memory in, I cannot get it to click (or get it deep enough for the lid to close). Are the dimensions different or do I need to push harder?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specs say that the 27" late-2013 RAM is 204-pin PC3-12800 while the late-2009 RAM is 204-pin PC3-8500. When you physically compare the RAM carrier boards, are they identical in height, width, thickness and indexing guide slot locations?

[image]

Red arrows are index guide slots.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot get the existing RAM out (it seems rather stuck). Therefore, I could only try shoving the new RAM into the open slots. I wanted to, but cannot compare.

Comment: After some comparing with the visible bits and measuring the depth, I had a renewed go. It took a _lot_ more strength than I had expected, but the new memory (both of them) are in. (Now let's see if it also works. :))

Comment: And the answer to that is... No. :( (beep beep beep)

Comment: RAM is incompatible, as I predicted. :-(